# Amazon EC2 instance user-data not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, user-data

I've created a new EC2 instance (t2.micro) and trying to deploy spring boot application. Application spring cloud aws dependency throwing some error related to instance user-data.

Then I executed `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/` on the instance but it returns 404.

[image]

FYI: `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/` is working fine.

Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

That's a correct response, if you do not specify `user-data` you'll receive `404`

```xml
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/
dynamic
meta-data


$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know what aws java sdk is expecting from user-data?

Comment: @hbamithkumara only if you provider ```user-data``` while launching the instance it will be available via the mentioned call. [using-instance-user-data](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/585591aca5161416dbf9bb717e9839ac3307dea3/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-aws.adoc#using-instance-user-data) this might be helpful